# Bitwise operator in js is inconsistent?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I know that there is a trick to make a decimal number into an integer using `x|0` :

for example :

`3.14|0`  -->`3`

There is no rounding involved here :

`3.999 |0 -->`3`

**Question**

However : why does

`9.99999999999|0` yields `9`

while

`9.9999999999999999|0` yields `10`?

Comment: I am more interested to know why that trick works. Could you please explain?

Comment: @thefourtheye In JavaScript, the `|` operator casts all it's arguments into two's complement signed 32bit integers.

Comment: @Oswald Thanks :) I also saw something similar, `~~FloatNumber`

Comment: @Oswald It seems to be the case 0x100000000|0 yealds 0.

Comment: The literal value in the script is parsed into a JavaScript number. That number is then cast into a 32but signed integer. JavaScript has rules about how to parse literals with too many decimal places into JavaScript numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`9.9999999999999999` has too many decimals and loses precision in Javascript representation, becoming 10. You can test this:
`9.9999999999999999 === 10` will be `true`

Comment: on the first sample there is also lose of precision since it is binary based represented `( 0.1+0.2 !=0.3)`  and it is also not acccurate.... so still my question remains

Comment: The answer is that the second number has the identical representation in memory as 10. Therefore, whether you do `9.9999999999999999|0` or `10|0`, it is exactly the same thing. The first number has the exact representation of `9.something`, so the result is 9.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to look in the source code of firefox, nonetheless it is interesting to try some samples:

```
>>> 9.99999999999999999.toString(2)
"1010"
>>> 9.9999999999999999.toString(2)
"1010"
>>> 9.999999999999999.toString(2)
"1001.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
>>> 9.999999999999999.toString(2).length
54
>>> 9.99999999999999.toString(2)
"1001.111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101"    
>>> 9.99999999999999.toString(2).length
53
```

Rough estimate: about 49 bits go into the mantissa which leaves 15 bits for sign and exponent.

Update: I found an interesting entry in the comp.lang.javascript FAQ, see http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#FAQ4_7
It limits the precision of a double type to 53 bits.

I think the precision is exhausted during the step when it converts the double into an 32-bit int prior to the bitwise logical or operation.